# Display of strings in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dynamic, dialog

How do I display an array of strings generated in random engine instead of 'first line'.. } in this program?

'status = {  'First line', ...
'Second line', ...

```
                'Third line', ...
                'Fourth line'};

    h = dialog('WindowStyle', 'normal', ...
        'Name', 'Randomised Devices', ...
        'Position', [100, 200, 350, 500]);

    uicontrol(h,...
        'Style', 'edit', ...
        'Units', 'normalized', ...
        'Position',[0.01 0.01 0.99 0.99], ...
        'BackgroundColor', [1 1 1], ...
        'Min', 1, ...
        'Max', 1000, ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'left', ...
        'String', status);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to go for displaying the cell, you may use

```
cell2str(status)
```

e.g.

```
[...] 'String', cell2str(status));
```

For a more sophisticated display, you may need to fill in "\n" to enforce line breaks, e.g. if you wanted to place each cell in a new line of the textbox:

```
statusstr = sprintf('%s\n',status{:})
```

(cf. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21308)

Comment: It gives an error.

Undefined function 'str2cell' for input arguments of type 'java.lang.String[]'.

Error in SMERCGUI>pushbutton1_Callback (line 286)
   status = {  str2cell(results2)};

@pyStarter

Comment: Depending on your Matlab release, the function cell2str (not str2cell) may not be included. You can retrieve it from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13999-cell2str

Comment: I use a R2012b, So I assume the function cell2str is already included and I think you haven't got my question clearly. 
I have concatenated few strings in a previous operation in the code and I want to display it instead of 'First Line... 'Second'..). So can you let me know how this will work ?
When I tried to replace status=(loads1) but it shows a blank GUI.
PS: I am new to GUI programming and need serious urgent help.
@Andrew Barber

Comment: If the function cell2str is not included, you may download it from the link I posted earlier. This has nothing to do with GUI programming. Basically, you need to transform the cell (the datatype you are using) into a string, which may be displayed in a textbox (in Matlab it is called "edit"). It is up to you, if the string is to be displayed as "{'a','b','c'}" or rather a<linebreak>b<linebreak>c.